# How can I overlay a png on every img tag on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok so here is my code:

```
<div class="latest-post">
    <a href="http://localhost/blaze/2011/documentaries/test-big-thumb" rel="bookmark">               
    <span>     
    <img width="140" height="100" src="http://localhost/blaze/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/DSC02798-140x100.jpg" class="attachment-latestvideos wp-post-image" alt="DSC02798" title="DSC02798" />
    </span>
    </a>   
</div>
```

I want to lay a 140px by 100px transparent .png element over the top of each img. I want this to fade in when the link is hovered by the user.

I can't do this with CSS sprites because the thumbnail images are being auto generated by wordpress and this has to be easy to use. I simply want jQuery to drop the png on top of the img elements.

This can't be that hard but I can't find an exact solution to this anywhere.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/). If you don't want to add the image on hover you could also append it in document.ready and simply make it visible when hovering the image.

```
<style>
  .hoverlink { display: block; position: relative; }
  .hoverPng { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; 
</style>

$("a.hoverlink").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).append("<img src='/stuff.png' class='hoverPng'>");
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find(".hoverPng").remove();
});
```